# How can I save a cron job?

Tags: cron

I have connected via ssh and have added a cron job but I can't figure out how to save it.  I'm still on the crontab -e page how do I save my changes?

Comment: in vim  :wq  in Emacs... exit then open vim :P

Comment: Actually the right answer for Emacs is `C-x` `C-s` to save and `C-x` `C-c` to quit.  (Just `C-x` `C-c` will offer to save any unsaved changes, too.)  ... These days there'd probably be a fugly menu you can access with `M-\`` if you don't have the mouse available.

Answer (score 1):

crontab -e simply fires up the crontab file for that account in your default text editor so you can edit it.

With nano, which is the default on ubuntu, you can hit `ctrl-x` then choose to save.

From the comments `:wq` for Vim and `C-x` `C-s` to save and `C-x` `C-c` to exit for emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Crontab is open, use your arrow keys to place the cursor at the beginning of the newly added Cron Job line and press the <kbd>i</kbd> key to insert text.

Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and type `:x` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit and save changes.